# Read file content in a zip file without unzipping?

Tags: linux, zip

Given a zip file `zipfile.zip`, we know that it contains a file called `text.txt`.

Is there a way to read the content of `text.txt` without unzipping `zipfile.zip`?

Comment: Define what you mean with "unzipping". And do you mean programmatically, or interactively?

Comment: Are you saying that you want the raw _compressed_ content of the the archive member `text.txt`?  I don't think you'll be able to do much with that, even if it's theoretically possible.  I *think* that the entire archive is compressed together, rather than the individual members being separately compressed, which would make it impossible to extract a single file without uncompressing it.

Comment: @TobySpeight Zip archive members are compressed individually. When you create a zip archive on the command line, the zip command displays how much each member is compressed.

Comment: Thanks @tml; that was something I was unsure of.  So it might be possible to extract, but the only use-case I can think of is to copy it into another Zip archive.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can dump the file directly to stdout, for example. You are still technically unzipping it, but not to disk:

```
$ unzip -p zipfile.zip text.txt
```

For example, to count the lines you could do this:

```
$ unzip -p zipfile.zip text.txt | wc -l
```

The `-c` option is similar, but will write the name of each extracted file right before the contents.

Comment: This works great, even if `zipfile.zip` contains a lot of files. I do not want to unzip `zipfile.zip` and check the content of `text.txt` because unzipping takes a long time.

Comment: @Idonknow you can unzip *one* file from a multi-file zip archive.

Answer (score 6):

libarchive's `bsdtar` supports a wide range of archive formats including infozip / pkzip ones, so you can use the same CLI for all of them:

```
bsdtar xOf zipfile.zip text.txt
```

Dumps the contents of the archive member(s) named `text.txt` on stdout. Add the `q` option to stop at the first (in practice, there's generally only one entry by a given path in an archive).

You'd do the same with `tar`, `tgz`, `iso`, `ar`, `cpio`, `7z` files, etc.

Answer (score 2):

If the zip file contains a single file you may use

```
zcat f.zip
zmore f.zip
zless f.zip
zgrep regexp z.zip
```

Those commands also work gziped files.
There are similar commands for bzip and xzip

```
bzcat bzmore bzless bzgrep bzdiff ...
xzcat ...
```

You can also use commands that know about compression formats. Example:

```
vim f.zip
vim f.bz2   ...
rg -z patter  z.zip     ## ripgrep recursive grep in compressed files
```